# Bot Traffic Identification Strategies

Tags: iis, logging, google-analytics, web-traffic, webtrends

Bots. Hate 'em.

**What I need to accomplish**
Like everyone else, I want to count up the number of times pieces of content get featured or are displayed as links without those numbers being artificially inflated by web bots.

**Why we can't just rely on Google Analytics**
GA does a nice job of validating the numbers they report, however they only report the main url, and not "related items" since "related items" is different per page-view/per user, we need to track those ourselves.

GA is a good standard against which we can hold our numbers against, but that's it.

**What I've done so far**

- Authenticated users are never hassled Firewall maintains IP Address
  blacklist
- Applications keep track of known bots
- **Nightly roll up jobs trawl our logs looking for the following signals:**
- Sustained bursts of requests  (high pages per second for more than x second)
- Blocks of requests blocks of IP addresses (x.y.z.245, .246, .247, .248, etc. cannot coincidentally be traipsing through our content at the same
  time)
- Pattern of landing page + requests for every page, in order, in rapid succession (humans rarely read every article, and not that quickly)

**What I am looking for**
Not vague advice, but actionable algorithms, or best practices, or articles which describe how approaches were actually implemented, with at least some pseudo-code snippets. I don't expect to get a silver bullet, but I know there are ways to approach this problem that I have not seen. I just need to see a good white paper or something.

**What I have seen a million times**

- "our company implements a multi-tiered approach with browser
  challenges and backend analytics, and blah blah blah" Sounds great, i'm sure the investors loved it, how about an actual example?
- So tired of CIO-Speak.  "we put hidden fields on our forms, it's
  called a honeypot!"

**Anything actually actionable would be most gratefully appreciated!!!**